# Dynamic invocation of a static "constructor" in C++

Tags: c++, static-methods

I'm trying to write a python wrapper of a closed source C++ library that has an interface like this:

```
class Image
{
  public:
    :
    static Image ReadImage(const char *Filename);
    :
}
```

The problem is that for the python binding I need a pointer to an `Image` object, and not the object `Image` itself. If the method was a constructor I would just do:

```
Image img = new Image();
```

but I'm stuck on whether there is a corresponding syntax to a static method. I tried the following which does not work (at least not in g++ 4.8):

```
image img = new Image::ReadImage("foo.bar");
```

Of course I can work-around this by generating a wrapper class, but I'm wondering if that is really necessary?

Comment: I fear you want a python class method ReadImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to rely on the copy-ctor or move-ctor:

```
Image* img = new Image(Image::ReadImage("foo.bar"));
```

Comment: (If dynamic storage duration is required; maybe putting it in a map or on the stack is sufficient.)

Comment: (If dynamic storage duration is required, use `std::unique_ptr` because otherwise your code is exception-unsafe and unmaintainable.)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! Luckily there was a working copy constructor, so your construct worked. I will accept this as an answer, though it would not work if there was no copy constructor.

Comment: @DyP I was trying to avoid making assumptions about the API that needs to be satisfied with this Python binding as the binding may take over the ownership.

Comment: @DanielFrey My comments aren't always meant as criticism. Your answer is quite short, so I wanted to add that it isn't the only solution :)

Comment: @DyP Understood and your comments are welcome (as well as rightfold's comment). I sometimes tend to be very brief in my answer because I don't want to confuse people with too many options, I should probably be a bit less brief in the future.

Comment: @DyP: When allocating an object in C++ it obviously needs to be released in C++, which can e.g. by done in the destructor of the returned PyObject. But that is a different question.

Comment: The answer is fishy (A memory leak is likely)!